# How to create a folder on windows server dynamically via server panel

Tags: windows, server, subdomain, cpanel, plesk

I am preparing a system that provides dealership. Member registration is like this, for example;

istanbul.seller.com
berlin.seller.com.

After the member registration is completed, I want the copy files to domains I specified on the server.

I' am lookin some APIs from plesk and cpanel that helps, but I don't know which way I shoulld go.
Your suggestions important for me
Thanks.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on SO